# Remove last elf from file

Tags: python, file, eof

**Problem** I want to remove eol (end of line and empty lines) from a file. The input file ended with text and eol. I am trying to remove the eol from file. After word list as written in text file there can have multiple lines ended with empty line or enter or \n

**Input file**

```
Testing
This

Wordlist

With

Returns

Between

word list
```

**Source code**

```
filename="input_file.txt"
with open(filename, 'r') as fn:
    for line in fn:
        if line != '\n':
            x = line
            print x,
#with open(filename, 'w') as foo:
    #foo.write(x)
```

Thanks for any suggestion and discussion.

Comment: It is good practice to end the last line with `\ņ`.

Comment: @Tichodromamuraria, not for ordinary text files. Text is text; there are no good or bad practices.

Comment: Yes, to merge the file in unix, but I want to remove eol in this case

Comment: `strip` the whole content.

Comment: @Tichodromamuraria strip does not work.

Comment: In this case use `rstrip`.

Comment: "does not work". How? What are you doing?

Answer (score 2):

Here is more efficient way than strip whole content - it doesn't put whole file content into memory - so it will be ok for huge files. This code buffers empty lines and only prints them when we got not empty line. So, last empty lines will not be printed.

```
prev_empty_lines = 0

with open(filename, 'r') as fn:
    for line in fn:
        if line != '\n':
            for i in xrange(prev_empty_lines):
                print '\n',
            prev_emply_lines = 0
            print line,
        else:
            prev_empty_lines += 1
```

Comment: Error- NameError: name 'x' is not defined. Can you please check. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Untested:</s>
Tested and corrected:

```
import os

filename="input_file.txt"
with open(filename, 'r') as fn:
    lines = filter(None, (l.strip() for l in fn))

data = os.linesep.join(lines).rstrip()

with open(filename, 'w') as foo:
    foo.write(data)
```

Notes:

- `os.linesep` could be replaced by a fixed EOL delimiter if you're targeting something specific.
- This method reads the entire file into memory, then manipulates it, then writes the manipulated data back to the file.  Depending on the size of your input file, this may be impractical.  See @KlassIvan's answer for a less memory intensive approach.

Comment: better use genexpr `filter(None, (l.strip() for l in fn))` than list. It's because `filter` creates brand-new list, so you are creating list twice.

Comment: Thanks @KlassIvan, updated and upvoted your alternate approach.